# Fetch values dynamically to a text field like a slider using php,mysql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

Their are two tables : `Table x( holds 'Areaname','datacount' coloumns) and Table Y (holds 'Areaname')`
User enters Areaname and datacount from a php page later it gets inserted to table x
my requirement:
If Areaname is new entry for Table Y then it gets inserted to 'table y' too
IF Areaname is matching with table y values while the user types the area name on the textfield
then a slider/dropdown which should show the Areanames which are matching for the word he is typing
if he still continues then its treated as new area and gets inserted to table y

```
Ex:
Areaname   |datacount
New york   | 1000
California | 500
```

user 2 enters california again then while typing 'cali' then it should check with 'table y' if matches then it shold show in the slider if not matches then it should be inserted to 'table y'
Thanks in advance mates . Few code snippets i have got here but didn't match for my requirements.

Comment: did u mean autocomplete like results? which one u are using? jqueryui?

Comment: i'm trying to do with javascript and jquery friend...

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can use Jquery to check this, for example using the function .change() you can catch the event when the user change the data in the input, so you can send a post every that the input change to a php file where receive what the user are typing and check the database for results, then you return the results, and with jquery you recive that data and you can put it in a table below the input with the results, so if the user are looking for something that you already have, the results in the table can help him to find it and with a button he can select the result. if he don't want select the result he simplify submit the result and everithing it's saved.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yourSelectId").change(function(){
         $.post("yourPHPfile.php",{str:$("#yourSelectId").value()},function(dataReturn){
             //process the data and put it in a table. if you use json_encode in php 
             //it's gonna be easire you can use a .each() of jquery to process every  
             //row in the json and then create an string with the html of the table 
             //with results and put it in your <table> with .html(stringHtml);
         });
    });
});
```

I think this is the easiest way to make it, there can be other option for example the autocomplete (jquery plugin) in a < select>. But I put you an option, let me know if you need more help. Regards. Have a nice day.